# Podemos colocar perguntas sobre melhoramento de código funcional?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Actualmente existe um site dedicado ao melhoramento de código que está a funcionar mas que pode ser optimizado, o [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

A minha questão é se vamos mover perguntas deste género para o Code Review ou se as mesmas serão válidas aqui?

Comment: Não podemos mover para o Code Review até porque ele não existe, pelo menos na versão pt. E mandar algo em português para o http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ não preciso dizer que é absurdo. Sou neutro nessa questão, por isso não vou uma resposta, mas como espero que não dividam o trabalho do desenvolvedor em diversos sites como ocorreu na versão original, o que eu classifico de erro, prefiro que seja aqui do que criar outro site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Levar perguntas daqui para o CodeReview (ou qualquer outro site da rede) é inviável, por causa da língua.

Quanto serem permitidas aqui, eu acredito que não seja um problema. A única regra por enquanto é que sua pergunta deve ser relacionada à programação. Satisfazendo esse requisito, vale (quase) tudo.

Comment: programação ou desenvolvimento de software? O SO é bem programação mesmo. Não sei de você viu todo o histórico da criação do site, originalmente o site até se chamava Software Development e era abrangente. O nome mudou mas a abrangência não. Você mesmo já postou algo animador que seria nesse sentido, posso considerar que foi apenas um lapso e o texto inicial que você postou é o mais preciso nisso?

Comment: Eu usei os termos de forma intercambiável... Não foi minha intenção conflitar com o texto anterior